# InAppSettingsKit - How to refresh titles/values programmatically?

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I am using the titlesForSpecifier feature to feed titles into IASK dynamically.  My titles array needs to be refreshed when another setting change.

e.g. list of state code for selection needs to be refreshed if user changes the country code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the code it should be fine to reset the `multipleValues` property of your specifier to `nil`. That should trigger reloading the titles from the delegate. Now to make `UITableView` refresh the cells, either use `reloadData` or `reloadRows(at:with:)`.

Comment: Awesome! Confirming this worked. I saved a reference to the specifier during the initial load and then perform `[stateCodeSpecifier setMultipleValuesDictValues:nil titles:nil];`